# Cypress - import and export functions

Tags: javascript, function, automation, cypress

How can I better organize my cypress code for testing so that I only need to import some functions?

I want to start by creating a file in which to authenticate on the page, and then I want to import it in a test with several functions.

I tried the following export code and it seems to have been incorrect, with errors:

```
export function login() {
    cy.visit('https://*********')
    cy.get('input[name="Parameter.UserName"]').type('*****')
    cy.get('input[name="Parameter.Password"]').type('*****')
    cy.contains('Login').click()

}

export default {login};
```

And in test :

```
import {login} from 'elements/pages/login.js'
```

Answer (score 8):

Your import needs a relative URL

```js
import {login} from '../elements/pages/login.js'  // relative from cypress/integration
```

or if under `cypress/suport/elements`

```js
import {login} from '../support/elements/pages/login.js'
```

Absolute imports (where path has no leading ./ or ../) are presumed to be library packages in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 3):

Cypress provides something called the **Custom commands** for this purpose, you can read about it [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands).

Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write all your code here like:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  cy.visit('https://*********')
  cy.get('input[name="Parameter.UserName"]').type('*****')
  cy.get('input[name="Parameter.Password"]').type('*****')
  cy.contains('Login').click()
})
```

And then in your any of your test, you can directly add:

```js
cy.login()
```

Comment: Great , thank you! Is there any way not to put all the commands in commands.js and somehow organize them on the pages (for example the Calendar page with some commands, the Settings page with other commands, the reservations page with other commands)?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You can create individual js files anywhere inside the project and then add the file path to `cypress/support/index.js` eg. Suppose I have a file `login.js `inside the `integration/utils` folder, All I need to do is add `import '../integration/utils/login.js'` in `cypress/support/index.js` file and it will work.

Comment: If i have "Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => { })", can i put several steps in this test? i mean several steps with a description of each

Answer (score 0):

all cys must be excuted in testing content, maybe u can try like this:

```js
export default {

    // props
    visit: (url)=> { return cy.visit(url) }
    get: (el)=> { return cy.get(el) }

    // methods
    login(){
      cy.visit('https://*********')
      cy.get('input[name="Parameter.UserName"]').type('*****')
      cy.get('input[name="Parameter.Password"]').type('*****')
      cy.contains('Login').click()
    }

}
```